# How to find length of longest continuous subarray such that first and last element are minimum and maximum?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, sub-array

How to find longest continuous subarray S[i..j] of array A[0..n-1] such that S[i] is minimal and S[j] is maximal element in S. It should be solved in O(N) or O(n log n).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add your approach along with any clarifying examples